# What is the big Oh complexity of this algorithm

Tags: java, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Need to find the Big O complexity for my solution of this [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/?tab=Description).

I am unable to estimate the complexity due to the repeated deletions from the queue when a repeating character is detected, without which it should be O(n) due to the single for loop that goes through the string.

Posting the gist of the problem and my solution for your reference :

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without
>   repeating characters.
>
> Examples:
>
> Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3.
>
> Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", with the length of 1.
>
> Given "pwwkew", the answer is "wke", with the length of 3. Note that
>   the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a
>   substring.

My solution:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        Queue<Character> q = new LinkedList<Character>();
        Hashtable<Character, Boolean> chars = new Hashtable<Character, Boolean>();
        int maxLen = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (!chars.containsKey(ch))
            {
                q.add(ch);
                chars.put(ch,true);
            }
            else
            {
                int len = q.size();
                System.out.println(len);
                while(q.peek()!=ch)
                {
                    chars.remove(q.remove());
                }
                q.remove();
                q.add(ch);
                if (len > maxLen)
                maxLen = len;
            }
        }
        if (q.size() > maxLen)
            return q.size();
        return maxLen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will be O(n). Whatever is inside the for loop is not that important, rather the number of times the loop will run is. This is because the inside part of the loop will be some arbitrary number of operations that will just be a constant. Since in big O we don't care about constants what is more important is the number of times the loop runs, which would be N.

Maybe some math could help demonstrate:

Say N = 5 and you don't know how many operations the loop will do, but you know it will run 5 times. First pretend that it only does one operation, then of course the number of operations is 5 which is 1*N. Then pretend the loop does 100 operations, then the number of operations is 500 which is 100*N. In both cases the big O is O(n). You can then assume that for some arbitrary number of loop operations that you will still get O(n). I don't know how valid that math is but the general idea makes sense.

Comment: But there is also a while loop in the for loop that could be called repeatedly. Won't that make a difference?

Comment: Oops I was looking at the website's solution and not yours, I didn't see that while loop. In that case, could you figure out what is the worst case for the while loop? Is there an example where you could have every if/else go to the else clause and then do the while loop n times?